# problems with installing WSS + SP 2 as a prereq of TFS 2008

Tags: team-foundation-server, wss

i have an issue when i attempt to run the following Command 
stsadm.exe -o extendvs -exclusivelyusentlm -url http://WSSServerName:80 -ownerlogin Domain\UserName -owneremail "admin@localhost" -sitetemplate sts -description "Default Web Site"

i replace the WSSServerName with my servername and provide the user i stated in the installation of WSS

however i get the error "Value does not fall within the expected range"

after digging around i found this post
http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Offtopic/thread/9b3fa4d9-66a1-45b8-9286-dd0c132b0070

and i tried making the changes suggest there inside WSS global settings, however i see no changed .

please help me understand what am i missing here i have followed microsoft installation guide 
"TFSInstall-08-SP1-July2010" and this step is listed there under the WSS section.

any help / pointers is more then welcome .

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That stsadm command provisions a sharepoint web application for use with TFS, but you can use the SharePoint UI to provision a Web application.

The link below is to someone with a similar problem. Your exact issue may be different, but the end result is the same: You just need to get the application created.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepointadmin/thread/576f7f19-1d3e-4080-b347-33db1af1f2d5

I write the TFS install guide. In the new one, we don't recommend stsadm; we just link out to the Sharepoint docs and suggest people use the UI to make a web app on port 80 with NTLM auth. The second link is to the sharepoint docs for how to create a web application -- basically just use the default settings.

Good luck!

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc287954(office.12).aspx

Comment: thanks for the help i managed to overcome the issue by doing it manually as you suggested.